# Ask about SMOTE in DMwR package

Tags: data-mining

I use SMOTE method by typing:
New<-SMOTE(Y~.,origin,perc.over=1300,k=5,perc.under=100)

But there is a warning:
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Y", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4",  : 
  'names' attribute [12] must be the same length as the vector [11]

I don't understand why this warning appearance. Someone help me please...

Comment: you can reference this


  [SMOTE column problem]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18349401/1114397